# Rendering a 3D object from four different angles

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine

I am working on a project where I have to render 4 different sides of a 3D object at the same time on the screen. The output should have 4 different camera outputs rendering the front side, left side, right side and back side of the 3d object.

I found that a gaming engine like Unity may help to do something like this. However, I have just started using Unity and can't figure out how to do it.

[Here is the link](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/27/holographiccar.jpg/) for some examples. This is how I want the output to look like

Comment: i tried a simple example of rendering a sphere and then added some lightning to it.. I got this from an online tutorial.. i have just started using Unity..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first of all, welcome to Stackoverflow. And you are right, Unity is an excellent IDE to achieve what you described.

As stated in the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), I'm going to give you an answer I deem fitting to your question. I can post the code here in about 30 minutes which does exactly what you asked for, but then we'd miss the point of learning to program and posting at StackOverflow in general. I'll show you the way on how to start on this project, but then you'll have to try yourself. If you have any troubles after trying some more, we can help you with specific problems, provided you have researched some before and show us what you tried.

As to your question, it's relative easy to do so. First create your object in the scene, then drag and place four different `Camera`-objects in the screen. Using the Camera's `Normalized View Port Rect`  (Four values that indicate where on the screen this camera view will be drawn, in Screen Coordinates (values 0-1)), you can then split up the view to show the feed of each Camera.

This ofcourse happens in a script. You can read [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Scripting.html) about Scripting in Unity. Even if you are an expert in programming, that link is worth a read when you are new to Unity.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I ll try to do what you suggested, and if in case i face any problems, i'll post it here.. thanks again.. :)

Comment: I tried dis thing..however m facing problem with the Normalized view port co-ordinates.. I set these co-ord's as .. For the cam at the front of the Obj: x =0.5 , y=0, =0.5, h=1 .. for d cam at the back : x=0.5, y=1,=0.5 h=1.. for the 1 at the left : x=0, y=0.5, And for the 1 at the right : x= 1 , y=0.5 .. . But the output is not what i wanted.. need help regarding how these view port co-ord's work..

Comment: `Normalized` means every parameter is between 0 and 1, with 1 being the entire width/height of the screen. So (.25, .25, .5, .5) means it starts a quarter of the way in from the left and bottom, and is 1/2 the screen width and height. So in your application, all your camera's need the last two parameters set to `0.5` since they all fill half the width and half the height. The first two are used for their locations, so your first Camera will start at (0,0). That means  your first camera is `(0, 0, 0.5, 0.5)`. I think you can figure out the rest now, else ask me again :)

Comment: I don't want to divide the output into 4 quadrants. Please take a look at the image I shared in the link. If I set the 1st Two co-ords of the camera1 as (0.0) .. I think, It will show the output at the top left corner, right ?. But i don' want it that way..

Comment: heyy.. thanx for the explanation.. i figured it out.. :) .. Now it works just the way i want.. thanxx again.. :)

Comment: Ah, you are correct. In that case, you'll have to do some maths. Think of the view divided in 9 squares, and you insert your camera views in 4 of the 9 squares. Then your Camera views should be in field 2, 4, 6 and 8. That would mean you'll have to start your first camera on `(11.1, 0, 11.1, 11.1)`, the second one on `(0, 11.1, 11.1, 11.1)`, the third on `(33.3, 11.1, 11.1, 11.1)` and the fourth on `(11.1, 33.1, 11.1, 11.1)`. This is untested so I might be wrong.

Comment: Oh ok! Was the code a bit like my comment, or did you do it differently? Also, if you found the answer(s) helpful, you can upvote or accept them if you like.

Comment: Now please guide me again.. The next thing i need to do is that.. I want to rotate the 3D object left and right using Arrow keys and the cameras should capture this changes in the object while they remain fixed at their location.. Also.. is their any way that i can change the 3d Object being displayed in the camera's through script dynamically.. like wen i press '2' a different 3d object replaces the location of current object..

Comment: actually the cord's dat i used wer : cam 1 (.33,0,.33,.33) , cam2(0,.33,.33,.33) and so on..

Comment: First of all, the comments aren't the place for lengthy explanations. Second of all, the comments aren't the place to ask a NEW question. Third of all, you haven't tried anything yourself yet. I'm not going to code your application for you, you can do that yourself. I'll only help people if they have strange errors or if they are stuck on something.

Comment: Ohh kk.. i dont want you to code my appln.. i just wanted to kno.. whether wat i wish is possible.. n how do i go about scripting..

Comment: It is certainly possible but also the basics of what one can do in Unity. I suggest going through some tutorials to get yourself comfortable with Unity3D.